# What is the best way to re-create plastic chair pad piece?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

This small chair pad (it's a metal bar stool, Ikea) broke and I thought I would use this as a good first Blender project.

My question is which way to build something like this?
Starting from a solid rectangular prism and then creating holes, or by a flat base, and then extrude and cut the circular profiles?

I have limited experience with Sketchup, but very little with Blender
Than you, Max

[image]

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad, please edit it and try focusing it on specific parts of the workflow you find yourself stuck in. I'd research [hard surface modelling](https://www.google.pt/search?tbm=vid&q=blender+hard+surface&gws_rd=cr&ei=EcrmWPyaBcSzUfeBi0A) and avoid going the tempting easy way of the *Boolean* Operations. Since it is a symmetric shape a *Mirror Modifier* may help.

Comment: @MaxM do you want to 3D print this element?

Comment: Yes, this is to be 3d printed. I understand that my question is not very specific, but that is exactly the question I want to ask. When I start working on it, I may have more specific questions​, but for now it's more about the design approach.

Comment: Check this tutorial of blender guru 4 parts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi87Dap_WOc and if you are going to 3D print it's ok if you got parts that overlap though it's better if you model it right without using the Boolean modifier